# UIAccessibilityCustomAction selector - why return BOOL

Tags: ios, accessibility, uiaccessibility

Why should the `selector` for `UIAccessibilityCustomAction` object return `BOOL`? What difference does it make whether it's true or false?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah finally I found that little note in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/SupportingAccessibility.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH12-SW1)...

> All special VoiceOver gesture methods return a Boolean value that determine whether to propagate through the responder chain. To halt propagation, return `YES`; otherwise, return `NO`.

Not as mysterious as expected.

Comment: Did you manage to pass the a parameter within the selector using UIAccessibilityCustomAction ? I'm trying to do this for couple of days

Comment: What `"the a parameter"` do you mean exactly?

Comment: actually I wanted to use swipe to delete a cell in a list and the VoiceOver wasn't working properly with it. I meant about passing the indexPath.row using the selector but this was not an option and now I got my problem solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48689384/4723935